# Sessions not showing up even after install

Tags: xubuntu, kubuntu

I tried installing Ubuntu and Kubuntu sessions on my Xubuntu session but they don't seem to show up.

I ran `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. I checked `/usr/share/xsession` and the only desktop file there is xubuntu. Can I create one of my own and link the exec of each desktop file to the start file. If this is possible where can find these start files?

**UPDATE**

I managed to get Kubuntu by making a file called `kubuntu.desktop` in my session folder and adding the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Kubuntu Session
Name[en_AU]=Kubuntu Session
Name[en_GB]=Kubuntu Session
Comment=Use this session to run Kubuntu as your desktop environment
Comment[en_AU]=Use this session to run Kubuntu as your desktop environment
Comment[en_GB]=Use this session to run Kubuntu as your desktop environment
Exec=startkde
Icon=
Type=Application
DesktopNames=Kubuntu
```

How do I do the same for Ubuntu? There is not start file associated with it in the `/usr/bin` directory.

Comment: Does your login screen not have gear icon anywhere?